# After importing image as plane the image is not shown, it is just a gray plane

Tags: image

After importing image as plane the image is not shown, it is just a gray plane.
[image]

Thanks if you can help me :)

Comment: Textures do not show in solid mode, use textured or rendered mode.

Answer (score 5):

*Image as Plane* doesn't work like *Reference* or *Background* images, if you want to see it in *Solid* mode you need to activate the *Texture* option:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Front View by pressing 1 numpad key
- Drag and drop your Image to blender Scene
- It's now imported as reference and always is textured

[image]

**Good luck .**